# jquery iframe form submit refreshes the page

Tags: forms, session, iframe, upload, refresh

I have a very strange problem.
Recently I've created an upload page using jquery form submit on an iframe (I don't want to refresh the page) and it worked perfectly.

When I put this code on my real page a weird problem appears.
I have a button with this code:

```
("#upload_button").click(function(){
    $("form").submit();
    })
```

But when I click it the whole page is refreshing and my user session disappears.
What could do this?

PS: My initial version works perfectly.

Oh yes.If I put a submit button it works too.But I want to do this submit with jquery on a div

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use not form tag, but form id parameter. Smth like $('#MyForm'). Using it this way will make you sure you are calling correct form.

Comment: I tried this and I get this: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function